# How to send a secret token to some static files through Github Pages

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I'm trying to get a token from Spotify WebAPI to some static files using GitHub. I already created a GitHub Workflow for my static files but I'm stuck on passing secrets tokens to my files. Here is my yaml code :

```yaml
name: GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
        with:
          path: '.'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

The secrets can be retrieved using :
`SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID` and `SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET`
On the other side, the code is made with HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Storing secrets on a static website is unsafe because everyone can get them and have access to them.  If you need to use secrets, you need to not use a static website.

Comment: Tagging this question with [yaml] is a useless and inappropriate as tagging it with [ascii], even though your "code" (YAML comes in documents) contains ASCII characters. Proper tagging helps people finding your question.